# как открыть из одного модального окна второе модальное окно

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap, modal

Столкнулся с проблемой модальных окон, а именно с задачей, когда при клике в одном модальном окне мне должно "вываливаться" второе. Первое модальное окно работает как надо, но при вызове второго окна происходит следующее:

1. первое модальное окно закрывается, но все остальное остается неактивным
2. второе модальное окно показывается под первым.
   Что я ожидаю: что я нажму на первое модальное окно и мне поверх него будет показываться второе, при закрытии второго мое первое окно станет вновь активным

Див блок куда будут загружаться модальные окна, страница Index.cshtml:

```
<div id="modDialog" class="modal fade">
    <div id="dialogContent" class="modal-dialog"></div>
</div>
<div id="modDialog2" modal="modal fade">
    <div id="dialogContent2" class="modal-dialog"></div>
</div>
```

Вызов первого модального окна:

```
    <div class="panel-line-nom" data-plain-mnemo="@Model.MNEMO_NAME" 
                            data-plain-stack="@item_karman.STACK_NAME" 
                            data-plain-pocket="@item_karman.POCKET_NUM">
@Html.ActionLink(@item_noms.DIAMETER, "GetKarmanDetails", new
{
   _stackName = item_karman.STACK_NAME,
   _pocketNum = item_karman.POCKET_NUM,
   _mnemoName = Model.MNEMO_NAME
}, 
new
{
   @class = "karmanItem"
})
</div>
```

обработчик нажатия этого события:

```
$("body").on('click', '.karmanItem', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var href = $(this).attr('href');
AJAXGlobals({
    url: href,

    data: {
        _mnemoName: $(this).data('plainMnemo'),
        _stackName: $(this).data('plainStack'),
        _pocketNum: $(this).data('plainPocket')
    },
    success: function (data) {

        $('#dialogContent').html(data.resultHtml);

        $('.table-custom').tableHover();

        $('#modDialog').modal('show');
        
    }
});
```

});

далее я в первом модальном окне(частичном представлении) вызываю второе модальное окно по ссылке следующим образом:

```
<div data-plain-mnemo="@Model.MNEMO_NAME" 
 data-plain-stack="@element.STACK_NAME" 
 data-plain-pocket="@element.POCKET_NUM"
 data-plain-diam="@element.DIAMETER"
 data-plain-thick="@element.THICKNESS"
 data-plain-stal="@element.STAL"
 data-plain-gost="@element.GOST">@Html.ActionLink("Номера труб", "GetPipeNumbers", new
    {
        _stackName = @element.STACK_NAME,
        _pocketNum = @element.POCKET_NUM,
        _mnemoName = @element.MNEMO_NAME,
        _diameter = @element.DIAMETER,
        _thickness = @element.THICKNESS,
        _stal = @element.STAL,
        _gost = @element.GOST
    }, new
        {
            @class = "sortItem"
        })
```

и обрабатываю это событие вот так:

```
$("body").on('click','.sortItem',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    AJAXGlobals({
        url: href,
        data: {
            _mnemoName: $(this).data('plainMnemo'),
            _stackName: $(this).data('plainStack'),
            _pocketNum: $(this).data('plainPocket'),
            _diameter: $(this).data('plainDiam'),
            _thickness: $(this).data('plainThick'),
            _stal: $(this).data('plainStal'),
            _gost: $(this).data('plainGost')
        },
        success: function(data) {

            $('#dialogContent2').html(data.resultHtml);

            $('.table-custom').tableHover();

            $('#modDialog2').modal('show');


        }
    });
});
```

наглядное представление что происходит при открытии первого модального окна:[image: первое модальное окно]

как видно, второе модальное окно располагается под первым:
[image: загрузка второго модального окна]

закрытие первого модального окна:вся страница становится не активной
[image: окно расположено на странице, а не поверх как модальное]

Кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

UPD: попробовал вставить модалку одну в другую вот так:

```
    <div id="modDialog" class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static">
        <div id="modDialog2" modal="modal2 fade2" data-backdrop="false">
           <div id="dialogContent2" class="modal-dialog2"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="dialogContent" class="modal-dialog"></div>

    </div>
```

И результатом является вывод второго модального окна на одном уровне, что и первое модальное окно:[image: вывод второго модального окна]

Как повесить второе поверх первого не понимаю

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/frames-and-windows

Answer (score 0):

Мое решение достаточно примитивное и простое.

второму модальному окну я задал параметр `z-index` немного больше, и отключил "модальность" этого окна атрибутом `data-backdrop="false"`

```
<div id="modDialog2" modal="modal2 fade2" data-backdrop="false" style="position:absolute; z-index: 2000;">
<div id="dialogContent2" class="modal-dialog" style="position: absolute; z-index: 2010;"></div>
```

[image: второе модальное окно стало поверх первого]